# Select multiple principals in Azure Keyvault Access Policy

Tags: azure, devops, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

While adding managed identities to the Keyvault Access Policy is easy

[image]

Now there's quite a few VMs that should be given access to the cluster.
It seems possible to select multiple managed identities add once and ascribe the same permissions to them, but I haven't managed to do this yet (ctrl + click, alt + click, selected multiple... all does not work). I cannot find it in the documentation either, however, it clearly states "selected item**s**" below. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign many managed identities at once. Neither for Portal nor via Azure CLI. You will need to assign one by one unfortunately..

Usually, Azure CLI is more capable of doing more jobs but it accepts only one assignee at a time.

```
az role assignment create --role
                          [--assignee]
                          [--assignee-object-id]
                          [--assignee-principal-type {Group, ServicePrincipal, User}]
                          [--condition]
                          [--condition-version]
                          [--description]
                          [--resource-group]
                          [--scope]
                          [--subscription]

Optional Parameters
--assignee
Represent a user, group, or service principal. supported format: object id, user sign-in name, or service principal name.

--assignee-object-id
Use this parameter instead of '--assignee' to bypass Graph API invocation in case of insufficient privileges. This parameter only works with object ids for users, groups, service principals, and managed identities. For managed identities use the principal id. For service principals, use the object id and not the app id.

--assignee-principal-type
Use with --assignee-object-id to avoid errors caused by propagation latency in AAD Graph.

accepted values: Group, ServicePrincipal, User
--condition
Condition under which the user can be granted permission.

--condition-version
Version of the condition syntax. If --condition is specified without --condition-version, default to 2.0.

--description
Description of role assignment.

--resource-group -g
Use it only if the role or assignment was added at the level of a resource group.

--scope
Scope at which the role assignment or definition applies to, e.g., /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333, /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup, or /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM.

--subscription
Name or ID of subscription. You can configure the default subscription using az account set -s NAME_OR_ID.
```

Checkout [Assign a managed identity access to a resource using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-cli).

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-assigned managed identity and grant it access to the Key Vault. Then assign the user-assigned managed identity to each VM.

This [blog](https://www.google.com/amp/s/thecodeblogger.com/2020/06/13/user-assigned-managed-identity-with-azure-key-vault/%3Famp=1) might help.